# go in insert mode after executing external command

Tags: vim

Here is my mapping:

```
autocmd FileType java inoremap <F5> <ESC>:upd\|!javac %<CR>:!java %:r<CR>
```

It does three things at once: saves, compiles, and runs java files. It works as expected but I want more from it.

Actually it happens that when the `.class` file is run and I press any key to enter the editor window, I remain in the normal mode, which I don't want to be. I want to enter insert mode as soon as I press any key.

I tried appending `i` to the mapping:

```
autocmd FileType java inoremap <F5> <ESC>:upd\|!javac %<CR>:!java %:r<CR>i
```

But this doesn't even gives time to view to output of `.class` file (i.e. it saves, compiles, executes, and goes into insert mode without pausing).

I want to do all the things that my first mapping is doing, along with changing to insert mode after pressing any key.

Answer (score 1):

You can wait for a keypress via `getchar()`. Append the following to your mapping:

```
:call getchar()<CR>
```

or, with message:

```
:echo "Press any key"<Bar>call getchar()<CR>
```

After that, you can re-enter insert mode via `i` or `:startinsert`

```
:echo "Press any key"<Bar>call getchar()<Bar>startinsert<CR>
```

Comment: Doesn't waits at output screen.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `:start<cr>` or `:norm i<cr>` at the end.

Comment: Does the work of going in insert mode, but doesn't waits at output screen to see the output.